# setPrimitiveValue:forKey: and to-many relationships

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

Apple's [documentation on `-setPrimitiveValue:forKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/setPrimitiveValue:forKey:) is vague in two ways when using it to manage to-many relationships.

First they state:

> If you try to set a to-many relationship to a new NSMutableSet object, it will (eventually) fail.

***Eventually?!*** What does that even mean? Will it fail later during `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]`? When an managed object is turned into a fault and then paged back in? When? Can I write a test case to consistently recreate the failure on-demand?

Second, providing sample code to correctly handle this case, they write:

> first get the existing set using `primitiveValueForKey:` (ensure the method does not return `nil`)

What should I do if/when the method *does* return nil? `assert()` it and fail immediately because that means the entire object graph is corrupted and saving will lead to data loss? `NSAssert()` on it as a warning to the caller but press on (silently doing nothing)?

Right now I'm simply directly assigning my desired `NS[Mutable]Set` in that case, like so:

```
- (void)setChildren:(NSSet*)value_ {
    NSMutableSet *mutableRelationshipSet = [[[self primitiveValueForKey:@"children"] mutableCopy] autorelease];
    if (mutableRelationshipSet) {
        [mutableRelationshipSet setSet:value_];
        [self setPrimitiveValue:mutableRelationshipSet forKey:@"children"];
    } else {
        [self setPrimitiveValue:value_ forKey:@"children"];
    }
}
```

Is that wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Just mutate the return value of `-primitiveValueForKey:` as a mutable set, trusting that its return value will do the right thing.

Be sure to also use `-willChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:` and `-didChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:` around your manipulation; you didn't show this in your above code.

```
- (void)setChildren:(NSSet *)value {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"children" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueSetSetMutation usingObjects:value];

    NSMutableSet *primitiveValue = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"children"];

    [primitiveValue setSet:value];

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"children" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueSetSetMutation usingObjects:value];
}
```

If you can target Leopard, you don't have to worry about this; you can use Core Data's built-in property support instead:

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Folder : NSManagedObject
@property (readwrite, retain) NSSet *children;
@end

@implementation Folder
@dynamic children;
@end
```

Core Data will generate not only a getter/setter pair for the `children` property but the mutable-set accessors as well, so you can use `-mutableSetValueForKey:` on it and manipulate the result with a minimum of overhead.